# This code works but should be a loop. How can I do that?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Works but is limiting.

I know it would be better with some iteration but not certain on how to best approach. For example, how would I check 20 items, rather than the 4 here, but code the "20" as var that I could easily switch to "30"?

```
    e0 = $('li:eq(0) a').attr('data-pubdate');
    e1 = $('li:eq(1) a').attr('data-pubdate');
    e2 = $('li:eq(2) a').attr('data-pubdate');
    e3 = $('li:eq(3) a').attr('data-pubdate');
    e4 = $('li:eq(3) a').attr('data-pubdate');


    if (e0 > lastCheckDate) {      
        thisEID = $('li:eq(0) a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };

    if (e1 > lastCheckDate) {    
        thisEID = $('li:eq(1) a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };

    if (e2 > lastCheckDate) {
        thisEID = $('li:eq(2) a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };

    if (e3 > lastCheckDate) {    
        thisEID = $('li:eq(3) a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };
    if (e4 > lastCheckDate) {    
        thisEID = $('li:eq(4) a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };
```

Comment: What does `sendNewOne` do?

Comment: Show us the loop code that you tried.

Comment: @Sampson Checks if this IED exists in an array and if true does a $.get.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's the value of `data-itemid` which is a string.

Comment: and what is it for? ... in a loop?

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much to all for such quick responses. They appear to employ different approaches to achieve what I'm confident will work. But, I get to study the variations which will help me learn. Perfect!

Comment: Unfortunate the question got downvoted so quickly. These all look like solid answers that could help others. Now, they'll likely get skipped over. Oh, well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a loop (Assuming you have 200 elements.)

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    if ($('li:eq(' + i + ') a').attr('data-pubdate') > lastCheckDate) {      
        thisEID = $('li:eq(' + i + ') a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has built in looping functions.

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var e = $(this).find('a').attr('data-pubdate');
    if(e > lastCheckDate){
        thisEID = $(this).find('a').attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do it like this

```
$('li a').each(function(){
    e = $(this).attr('data-pubdate');
    if (e > lastCheckDate) {      
        thisEID = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For you case you can do the following.

```
var elements = 5;

for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
    var element = $('li:eq(' + i + ') a');

  if (element.attr('data-pubdate') > lastCheckDate) {      
      thisEID = element.attr('data-itemid');
    sendNewOne();
    }
}
```

You could also get the total elements like this.

```
var elements = $('li a');

$.each(elements, function () {
  if ($(this).attr('data-pubdate') > lastCheckDate) {      
      thisEID = $(this).attr('data-itemid');
    sendNewOne();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$.each()`:

```
$.each($('li a'), function(index, anchor)
{
    var pubdate = $(anchor).data('pubdate'); // Use .attr('data-pubdate') for dynamically generated elements

    if (pubdate > lastCheckDate)
    {
        thisEID = $(anchor).data('itemid');
        sendNewOne();
    }

});
```